# find index value in list on dart language

Tags: dart

i have a list

```
var lst = [ "test0" , "test1" , "test2" , "test3"];
```

I want to search inside this list and find the "test2" index.
Is there such a function within the dart language?

```
//lst.find("test2") -> 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [List.indexOf](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/List/indexOf.html).

```
lst.indexOf('test2');
```